# Targetting a variable with a toggle button

Tags: jquery-mobile, html5-audio

I have got my HTML5 project a bit further along - I have one last stumbling block which is: I have set a variable and have three buttons which give it a different value - each value should relate to a different mp3 file, I want my big 'play' button to play whichever mp3 ( variable) has been selected. I then want the button to toggle off or stop playing when clicked again.

I'm out of my depth a bit ( on tip toes) so any help/advice would be appreciated. I have gone through the Jquery and html5 audio notes but can't find anything too helpful ( that I can understand anyway!)

Thanks for any help,

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CZLcR/29/

JS

```
var selectedMP3;

$('input[name=mp3_option]').change(function() {
    selectedMP3 = $('input[name=mp3_option]:checked').val(); 
});

$('#controlButton').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.text() == 'Play') {
        $this.children().children().text('Pause');
    } else {
        $this.children().children().text('Play');
        alert('Stopped playing song: '+selectedMP3);
        $('input[name=mp3_option]').attr('checked',false).checkboxradio('refresh');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a song:</legend>
             <input type="radio" name="mp3_option" id="radio-choice-1" value="song-1.mp3" />
             <label for="radio-choice-1">MP3 1</label>

             <input type="radio" name="mp3_option" id="radio-choice-2" value="song-2.mp3"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-2">MP3 2</label>

             <input type="radio" name="mp3_option" id="radio-choice-3" value="song-3.mp3"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-3">MP3 3</label>

             <input type="radio" name="mp3_option" id="radio-choice-4" value="song-4.mp3"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-4">MP3 4</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>


        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="controlButton">Play</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Phill - thanks so much for taking the time to work on this question - it's absolutely spot on. I can now see how you've done it and learn for next time :) Much appreciated -Jim

Comment: Slight snagette - I can't get it to play the mp3 - just keeps returning 'undefined' or '8000.mp3' ( the first audio file selection) it returns the same 8000.mp3 for the other options too - I've checked and the file is definitely in the right place.. any clues? Thanks Jim

Comment: I noticed looking at the source of that output frame on jsfiddle that it added $(window).load(function(){ - if I add this it makes the pause/play function work, but still returns 'undefined' on the mp3?

Comment: Hi - still can't get it to function:test page at:
http://www.madhouse1.com/jim/#page2

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to you demo, I found the problem. You are using jQM Alpha version 1.0a3 please update the jQM library to the current version: http://jquerymobile.com/download/ also Votes up are nice as well

Comment: Hi - thanks - I tried updating to the latest lib but it breaks it ( see same link) - any idea why? Thanks, Jim

Comment: Yes jQM Alpha has different structure and function calls, I would look at the current documentation and make the necessary changes

Comment: Well - all libs and calls amended - all works apart from actually playing the audio. Same link... thanks again for your help! Jim

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for phonegap.js and jim_gradient.css

Comment: Sorry - should be ok to check now

Comment: http://www.madhouse1.com/phonegap.js still gives a 404 response would suggest hosting your own version http://phonegap.com/

Comment: madhouse1.com/jim/phonegap.js is responding ok here? There is a version on there as that's the dir where the html file is hosted?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and hitting this link: http://www.madhouse1.com/jim/#page2 I right click and inspect element, click on the console tab and I see a 404 for this file: http://www.madhouse1.com/phonegap.js

Comment: Ah - ok that's weird - I'm using Safari - I'll stick a copy of phone gap.js in the root anyway - thanks Jim